# Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page Showing Up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, vagrant, unicorn

Have been working with Rails 5 and setting up everything through Vagrant. I have successfully been able to get my site working through Nginx and Webrick. When I try with Unicorn, it shows me the Apache2 default page. I removed the default in `sites-available` and created one under `sites-enabled` which is linked to `nginx.conf`.

**Here is my `nginx.conf` file:**

```
upstream unicorn {
  server unix:/tmp/unicorn.mysiteNginx.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 80 default deferred;
  # server_name projectname.com;
  root /vagrant/public;
  try_files $uri/home.html $uri @unicorn;
  location @unicorn {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://unicorn;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
  }
```

**`unicorn.rb`** file:

```
working_directory "/vagrant"
pid "/vagrant/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid"
stderr_path "/vagrant/log/unicorn.log"
stdout_path "/vagrant/log/unicorn.log"

listen "/tmp/unicorn.mysiteNginx.sock"
worker_processes 2
timeout 30
```

**`unicorn_init.sh` file:**

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
# Example init script, this can be used with nginx, too,
# since nginx and unicorn accept the same signals

# Feel free to change any of the following variables for your app:
# Remember -E production flag for production & sudo -c "$CMD" - user so it's not run as root!
TIMEOUT=${TIMEOUT-60}
APP_ROOT=/vagrant
PID=$APP_ROOT/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid
CMD="/home/vagrant/.rvm/bin/ruby-2.3.1_unicorn -D -c $APP_ROOT/config/unicorn.rb -E production"
action="$1"
set -u

old_pid="$PID.oldbin"

cd $APP_ROOT || exit 1

sig () {
        test -s "$PID" && kill -$1 `cat $PID`
}

oldsig () {
        test -s $old_pid && kill -$1 `cat $old_pid`
}

case $action in
start)
        sig 0 && echo >&2 "Already running" && exit 0
        su -c "$CMD" - vagrant
        ;;
stop)
        sig QUIT && exit 0
        echo >&2 "Not running"
        ;;
force-stop)
        sig TERM && exit 0
        echo >&2 "Not running"
        ;;
restart|reload)
        sig HUP && echo reloaded OK && exit 0
        echo >&2 "Couldn't reload, starting '$CMD' instead"
        su -c "$CMD" - vagrant
        ;;
upgrade)
        if sig USR2 && sleep 2 && sig 0 && oldsig QUIT
        then
                n=$TIMEOUT
                while test -s $old_pid && test $n -ge 0
                do
                        printf '.' && sleep 1 && n=$(( $n - 1 ))
                done
                echo

                if test $n -lt 0 && test -s $old_pid
                then
                        echo >&2 "$old_pid still exists after $TIMEOUT seconds"
                        exit 1
                fi
                exit 0
        fi
        echo >&2 "Couldn't upgrade, starting '$CMD' instead"
        su -c "$CMD" - vagrant
        ;;
reopen-logs)
        sig USR1
        ;;
*)
        echo >&2 "Usage: $0 <start|stop|restart|upgrade|force-stop|reopen-logs>"
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
```

Before submitting this question, I did some research on stack overflow and did some troubleshooting with similar question but no success so far. Any help would be appreciated!

**---UPDATE 1---**

This is what shows in `error.log` when I do `sudo service unicorn restart`:

```
017/08/07 22:41:17 [notice] 2387#2387: signal process started
2017/08/07 22:41:18 [emerg] 2391#2391: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2017/08/07 22:41:18 [emerg] 2391#2391: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2017/08/07 22:41:18 [emerg] 2391#2391: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2017/08/07 22:41:18 [emerg] 2391#2391: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2017/08/07 22:41:18 [emerg] 2391#2391: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2017/08/07 22:41:18 [emerg] 2391#2391: still could not bind()
```

**---UPDATE 2---**

Log after `sudo lsof -i:80`

```
COMMAND  PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
nginx   1854     root    6u  IPv4  11471      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   1855 www-data    6u  IPv4  11471      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```

Comment: You need to see nginx logs. Sometimes is because you need to create tmp and pids directories.

Comment: Do you need an Apache2 process running aside? If you don't, try to stop it.

Comment: And you need to define server_name.

Comment: Check in the update above for what shows in error.log. As for creating `tmp` and `pids` directories, those were created in side my `vagrant` folder where my project relies with a `unicorn.pid`.

Comment: @AndréGuimarãesSakata I already stopped it but it and it shows an empty response

Answer (score 3):

At first you should be run ***

> sudo systemctl stop apache2

---

after that

> sudo systemctl restart nginx

> sudo systemctl reload nginx

Answer (score 0):

The EADDRINUSE (98) error is pretty clear. You can't have multiple webservers bind(2) to port 80. One of them will have to go, to make room for the one you prefer.

Use `sudo lsof -i:80` to identify the process that has already bound to that TCP port. Root should issue a `kill`, or a command like `service apache stop` to temporarily allow another server to acquire the port. Longer term, something like `systemctl disable apache` will ensure port 80 is still free after reboot. Or switch to a non-default port in its config file.

Comment: Yeah, I also expected that would be the issue by reading the log. I am going to try your method when I get back. What I do know is that I have stopped apache by doing `sudo service apache2 stop` and nothing would happen. If I would reload vagrant and restart both nginx and unicorn, apache would be up and running. Its either kill it completely (like you are recommending) or remove apache completely from the server.

Comment: Added a second update to my question after using `sudo lsof -i:80`. Didn't see any `kill` next to root. I also used `systemctl disable apache` but it says that command not found. Another thing is that I finally decided to uninstall apache 2 just to see if it could work.